# Howto create an Eclipse Library?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How do I convert my Eclipse plugin so it is seen in Eclipse as a Libary, like JUnit, for example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be taken care of by the [Deploy step](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#deployplugin)
(from the excellent **[vogella.de tutorials section](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html)**,
specifically the [vogella's "Eclipse Products and Deployment - Tutorial"](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html))

[image: overview]

> Switch now to your product configuration file and select the tab Overview. Click on the "Eclipse Product export wizard" to export your product.

[image: select export]

> Select the plugin you want to export.

[image: export]

> **This will create a jar in the directory plugin**. Copy this jar to the "dropin" directory in your Eclipse installation directory and re-start Eclipse. Your plugin should now be available.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the tutorial and the "Product project".